# Pycharm 2022.3 hangs when opening project

Tags: pycharm

My Pycharm is currently playing up. Whenever I open it and choose a project it immediately hangs (specifically when it starts scanning files to index). In one of my attempts I got a notification saying "file system cache corrupted". After some extensive google search all the options I found require the GUI since you have to click on "File > blah blah".

Since my Pycharm hangs right after choosing the file to open I can't click on "File > ... " since this upper bar only appears when the project is opened.

Thus, anyone know a way to clear the cache from terminal? what path must be clear in order to do exactly what Pycharm does when clicking there?

Thanks in advance